# SSD I/O errors and timeouts on Raspberry Pi — but fine on Windows?

Tags: linux, ssd, hardware-failure, raspberry-pi, sata-to-usb

I'm using an SSD for data storage conntected with an USB-to-SATA adapter to my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.

Everything was running fine for about a year, but now it looks like the SSD is failing. The first thing I noticed was a remount as read-only, and now I'm getting repeatedly I/O errors and timeouts (see *syslog* excerpt below).

Assuming the SSD is going to die, I bought a new one (same model). But while deploying the backup to the new SSD I got the same errors and timeouts again. So the new SSD is already defective?

Then I connected both SSDs (old and new) to my Windows PC, reformatted them and did some read/write tests: Everything seems to be fine. Even the SMART data did not show any issues.

So where is the real problem? The SSD or the adapter (although working fine on Windows)? Or the Raspberry Pi/Raspbian?

```
Aug  8 19:41:07 pi kernel: [ 1807.427150] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x05 driverbyte=0x08
Aug  8 19:41:07 pi kernel: [ 1807.427185] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x2 [current]
Aug  8 19:41:07 pi kernel: [ 1807.427204] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1
Aug  8 19:41:07 pi kernel: [ 1807.427228] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 06 c4 bc 48 00 00 20 00
Aug  8 19:41:07 pi kernel: [ 1807.427248] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 113556552
Aug  8 19:41:07 pi kernel: [ 1807.428089] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
Aug  8 19:41:07 pi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Mon Aug  8 19:42:07 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Aug  8 19:41:56 pi kernel: [ 1856.578961] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Aug  8 19:41:56 pi kernel: [ 1856.578996] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x2 [current]
Aug  8 19:41:56 pi kernel: [ 1856.579015] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1
Aug  8 19:41:56 pi kernel: [ 1856.579039] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 01 29 08 00 00 08 00
Aug  8 19:41:56 pi kernel: [ 1856.579058] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 76040
Aug  8 19:41:56 pi kernel: [ 1856.579215] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): __ext4_read_dirblock:970: error -5 reading directory block (ino 2, block 0)

Aug  8 19:47:57 pi kernel: [ 2217.391824] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x05 driverbyte=0x08
Aug  8 19:47:57 pi kernel: [ 2217.391857] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x2 [current]
Aug  8 19:47:57 pi kernel: [ 2217.391876] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1
Aug  8 19:47:57 pi kernel: [ 2217.391899] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 06 c4 08 00 00 00 08 00
Aug  8 19:47:57 pi kernel: [ 2217.391919] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 113510400
Aug  8 19:47:57 pi kernel: [ 2217.391939] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 14188544, lost sync page write
Aug  8 19:47:57 pi kernel: [ 2217.392074] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
Aug  8 19:48:28 pi kernel: [ 2248.391304] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
Aug  8 19:48:59 pi kernel: [ 2279.341526] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the issue was related to the Raspberry Pi's power supply, that's why the SSD only failed when connected to the Pi. Probably it didn't have enough power to serve the SSD over USB.

I replaced the power adapter and removed the USB extension cable, using a normal power cable. Now the SSD works flawlessly again.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the SSD directly to an open SATA port on your desktop and boot from a Linux live CD. If you don't see any errors, shutdown and reattach it using the adapter. Boot again and see if the errors appear. If still no errors then there's something wrong with the pi.